# Amazon Search Ads not showing in rails App

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, amazon-advertising-api

### Issue

Amazon Search Ads are not showing up in my rails app. It's like the javascript script is not running.

### Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    amzn_assoc_placement = "adunit0";
    amzn_assoc_search_bar = "true";
    amzn_assoc_tracking_id = "livingrecipe-show-recommendation-20";
    amzn_assoc_search_bar_position = "bottom";
    amzn_assoc_ad_mode = "search";
    amzn_assoc_ad_type = "smart";
    amzn_assoc_marketplace = "amazon";
    amzn_assoc_region = "US";
    amzn_assoc_title = "Shop Required Equipment";
    amzn_assoc_default_search_phrase = '<%= escape_javascript(equipment) %>';
    amzn_assoc_default_category = "All";
    amzn_assoc_linkid = "78aa42b54ebf16f31c5239f132e3d7a0";
    amzn_assoc_rows = "1";
</script>
<script src="//z-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/onejs?MarketPlace=US"></script>
```

When the webpage renders that code is there and it creates a  but there is nothing inside it.  Here is a screenshot of what it looks like when I inspect it.  Also there are no errors on the page when it loads.
[image: Screenshot]

EDIT: I am using Turbolinks and think it might be an issue with that

Comment: Do you have this deployed anywhere or just local on your computer?

Comment: it is deployed at living-recipe.com, just got some test data up right now but if you view one of the recipes it should be displayed right below Ingredients/Directions and above comments

Comment: I don't even see the script on your page. are you sure that it compiled before you deployed?

Comment: Im sure, i took that screenshot from the live site not my local one.  Need to go to a recipe and its in a dive near the bottom of the page

Comment: same issue ..If someone has solution,please let me know

Answer (score 1):

As per [this Forum discussion](https://engagedforums.com/discussions/Amazoncom_Associates/Discussions/Native_ads_displaying_blank_box/am-associhelp/49012.1?redirCnt=1&dbg=6&nav=messages&mobile=y), **Search Ads** does not work, use **Custom Ads** instead.

See! you will see 3 options, click on "Custom ads" and get your js script.

[image]